# Report Broken WOTC forum links here. Help us fix them

Tags: discussion

WOTC just changed their entire forum structure and linking. This question will help us track and repair the damage to our site.

Please add broken links here as you find them.

- [Is it possible to roll Stealth versus multiple targets when one or more can see you?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/is-it-possible-to-roll-stealth-versus-multiple-targets-when-one-or-more-can-see/14408#14408) Fixed.
- [When a creature is invisible, but not hidden, do the enemies know the location of the creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4828/when-a-creature-is-invisible-but-not-hidden-do-the-enemies-know-the-location-o/4829#4829) Half-fixed?
- [Can I hide using Cunning Sneak with Wilderness Skirmisher?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27230/can-i-hide-using-cunning-sneak-with-wilderness-skirmisher/27236#27236) Fixed.

Please help us fix these a few at a time.

An update, it looks like they are trying to fix some of the links internally via redirects and whatnot. Please continue to update links as your come across broken ones.

Comment: It really is tiresome that they keep doing this.

Comment: I got the Rules of Hidden Club link for the invisible-but-not-hidden question, but not the rules reference, which wants me to log in. Not sure if that's a broken link or if I just lack the appropriate subscription.

Comment: @KRyan rules references should still be good as those are compendium links

Comment: @KRyan WotC is pretty incompetent when it comes to technology. I haven't followed the details recently, but I had been following their antics since before the days of the GleeMax apocalypse and the constant MTGO server breakages. They (at least used to) find their "tech" people by promoting by Peter Principle amateur programmers they discovered in their non-tech departments!

Comment: If it wants you to log in, that's because their 404 is ... protected. ::grumble:: Report all request login links cause... they're not actually requesting login.

Comment: I'll be going through all 380 of my 4e answers and fixing them...

Comment: the protected 404 is the biggest wtf of the whole thing.

Comment: Converted to community wiki.

Comment: Their migration to the new forums was sloppy at best and malicious at worst. They took an old snapshot of the forums and converted it, losing about a two weeks worth of data in the process: very sloppy for such a wealthy company whose target userbase is more tech savvy than the average person too!!

Comment: @corsiKa This is like the third or fourth time they’ve done this. On some level we should be glad we lost “only” two weeks’ worth of stuff. The internet abounds with dead links to old Gleemax threads, many of them major repositories of important information that had long histories on the forum.

Comment: WOTC may be shuffling things intentionally, in order to discourage deep linking.

Comment: @aramis I don't think so, they've fixed *most* of the redirects. They broke their own internal forum links too.

Answer (score 3):

[Data Explorer Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/role-playing%20games/query/136845/posts-with-community-wizards-com-links)

Like all data explorer queries, it's updated once a week. I've put user and score in there, so fix your own answers first. Edit this answer to show which users have been fixed.

Comment: Is this something that still requires action? I see one of my answers in the query, but the link appears to be working without intervention.

Comment: The consensus on the forums is "We don't know when they'll break the links again, so let's go ahead and fix everything anyways". Mind you, it's now *much* easier to see where the links resolve to, since clicking through (generally) gets you to your intended destination.

Comment: Thanks for setting this up, Brian.